# magento custome tab in manu give 404 page not found error

Tags: magento-1.9, forms

here is my all file Every time i got page not found error i also clear all my cashe still it not working
config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Sample_Bigcom>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </Sample_Bigcom>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <helpers>
                <sample_bigcom>
                    <!-- Helper definition needed by Magento -->
                    <class>Mage_Core_Helper</class>
                </sample_bigcom>
            </helpers>
        </global>
        <admin>
            <routers>
                <adminhtml>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                            <Sample_Bigcom before="Mage_Adminhtml">Sample_Bigcom_Adminhtml</Sample_Bigcom>
                        </modules>
                    </args>
                </adminhtml>
            </routers>
        </admin>
<layout>
    <updates>
        <sample_bigcom>
            <file>sample_bigcom.xml</file>
        </sample_bigcom>
    </updates>
</layout>
    </config>
```

sample_bigcom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0.0">

    <adminhtml_bigcom_index>
        <update handle="editor"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="sample_bigcom/adminhtml_form_edit" name="bigcom"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="sample_bigcom/adminhtml_form_edit_tabs" name="bigcom_tabs"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_bigcom_index>

</layout>
```

adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <mycustomtab module="sample_bigcom" translate="title">
            <title>My Custom Tab</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <index module="sample_bigcom" translate="title">
                    <title>Index Action</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/bigcom</action>
                </index>
            </children>
        </mycustomtab>
    </menu>
    <adminhtml>
    <acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <sample>
                    <title>My Custom Tab</title>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <index>
                            <title>Index Action</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </index>
                    </children>
                </sample>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

data.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Adminhtml base helper
 *
 * @category   Mageworks
 * @package    Mageworks_Import
 * @author     mageworks kumar <mageworksnsscoe@gmail.com>
 */
class Sample_Bigcom_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

AdminformController.php

```
<?php

class Sample_Bigcom_Adminhtml_AdminformController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{


    /**
     * View form action
     */
   public function indexAction()
    {

        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('mycustomtab')
            ->_title($this->__('Index Action'));
$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('form/adminhtml_form_edit'))
        ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('form/adminhtml_form_edit_tabs')); 
        // my stuff

        $this->renderLayout();
    }



}
```

Edit.php

```
<?php

class Sample_Bigcom_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_objectId = 'edit_form';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'form';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_form';

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('form')->__('Save'));
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('form')->__('Delete'));

    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        return Mage::helper('form')->__('My Form Container');
    }

}
```

Form.php

```
<?php

class Sample_Bigcom_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    /**
     * Preparing form
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
            array(
                'id'     => 'edit_form',
                'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save'),
                'method' => 'post',
            )
        );

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Tabs.php

```
<?php
class Sample_Bigcom_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{

  public function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->setId('form_tabs');
      $this->setDestElementId('edit_form'); // this should be same as the form id define above
      $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('form')->__('Product Information'));
  }

  protected function _beforeToHtml()
  {
      $this->addTab('form_section', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('form')->__('Item Information'),
          'title'     => Mage::helper('form')->__('Item Information'),
          'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('form/adminhtml_form_edit_tab_form')->toHtml(),
      ));

      return parent::_beforeToHtml();
  }
}
```

i tried lot on this didnt get any answer
can anyone please give me solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things missing. First in your `config.xml`

Where you are delcaring your admin route you have the module as `foo_bar` instead of your module handle `sample_bigcom`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
       <admin>
            <routers>
                <adminhtml>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                            <sample_bigcom before="Mage_Adminhtml">Sample_Bigcom_Adminhtml</sample_bigcom>
                        </modules>
                    </args>
                </adminhtml>
            </routers>
        </admin>
  </config>
```

You also need to update your controller to be `bigcomController` which lives in `controllers/Adminhtml`. This was declared in your `adminhtml.xml` as your action `<action>adminhtml/bigcom</action>`

You should take a look at this post for more information: http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited

**EDIT:**

You will also need to update your blocks in `bigcomController`. In your `config.xml` you need to declare your blocks:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
       <sample_bigcom>
           <class>Sample_Bigcom_Block</class>
       </sample_bigcom>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

you will also need to change your block to `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('sample_bigcom/adminhtml_form_edit')`

Comment: thank you so much i got my solution but after that i got just pain blank page...how can i solve this?

Comment: Is there any information in the `error.log` or `exception.log`?

Comment: no there is not any information

Comment: can you add a `die('test')` statement to your bigcomController

Comment: got test word and again try to reolad original after that i got this error:2015-08-07T08:19:43+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_addLeft() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract, boolean given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\magentosample77\app\code\local\Sample\Bigcom\controllers\Adminhtml\BigcomController.php on line 17 and defined  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magentosample77\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Controller\Action.php on line 126

Comment: Ah ok then so that means the controller is working but it doesn't look like your blocks are loading. I'll update my answer

Comment: i declared blocks in my config.xml file but still its not working

Comment: You will need to change how your getting the blocks. See my answer again

Comment: got this error : Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Form_Helper_Data' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magentosample77\app\Mage.php on line 547

Comment: That's cause you haven't fully decalerd your helper. When you are using it in your form_edit block you have `Mage::helper('form')` but it should be `Mage::helper('sample_bigcom')` after you have declared it.

Comment: ok got you now error is gone but still getting blank page..please one more help

Comment: Ok so your getting a blank page which means that nothing is broken t just means your blocks won't be printing out. What are you trying to do in your module?

Comment: i am just trying to display one form for input file and after that want to submit and upload that file to specific folder

Comment: i just add new topic for this problem you can refer this  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/77085/magento-cant-load-block-via-controller